# The Scope of the Persistence Context of Container Managed Entity Manager

Tags: java, jpa, entity, persistence

I have two entities and a session bean as below:

```
@Entity
public class Manager {

    @Id
    private int managerId;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager")
    private Set<Department> departments;

    //... constructors, getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Department {

    @Id
    private int departmentId;
    @ManyToOne
    private Manager manager;

    //... constructors, getters and setters

}

@Stateless
public class JPADao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void addDepartment(Department department) throws Exception { 
        entityManager.persist(department);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Property> getAllDepartments() throws Exception {        
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("SELECT d FROM Department d").getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Department> searchDepartmentByManager(Manager manager) throws Exception {
        manager = entityManager.find(Manager.class, manager.getManagerId());
        manager.getDepartments().size();
        entityManager.refresh(manager); //it won't work if I remove this line

        return manager.getDepartments();
    }
```

For testing purpose, I have manually loaded some managers with no departments in the database.

After a call to `addDepartment()`, a department is added successfully and the relationships is set up (the department record has a fk associated with the corresponding manager). The change is also shown when I call `getAllDepartments(`). However, if I call `addDepartment()` again, and call `searchDepartmentByManager()` by passing a detached manager object, the manager object that is returned by the `entityManager.find()` will not contain the department that has just been added. It will only become aware of the change when the `entityManager.refresh(manager)` is called.

What I don't understand is that, why doesn't the `entityManager.find()` returns a manager with the latest data? I checked that in the database between calling `addDepartment()` and `searchDepartmentByManager()` and the department object is added successfully at the time. Somehow it just doesn't show up in the `entityManager.find()` until the `entityManager.refresh(manager)` is called. I have a feeling it is about the scope and lifetime of the persistence context and I would like to find out the details about it.

I would really appreciate if someone can answer this questions.

With thanks,
Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `entityManager.find(...)` if the `Manager` entity instance is contained in the persistence context, it is returned from there.

With `entityManager.refresh(...)` the `Manager` entity instance will be overwritten with the values from the DB.

What I suspect is happening is that the `Manager` instance you are passing to `searchDepartmentByManager(...)` is not detached. It seems to be attached to the persistence context **and** it is outdated (since it does not have the latest `Department`(s)).

You can try persisting/merging the entities in the right order to maintain parent-child responsibility of the mapping. This is described over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746318/jpa-onetoone-bidirectional). *(note that the link talks about one to one relationship but the solution should apply to all types of bidirectional relationships)*